# Block multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Ok, so here goes another problem:

Instructions say to block multiply:

[image]

Im stuck at the end where there is clearly something wrong.

Matrix B is:
$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$

..in case its not legible. Sorry for the bad photo :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last block multiplication, you should write $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \left[ 0 \atop 0\right] = 0$ instead of $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \left[ 0 \atop 0\right] = \begin{bmatrix} 0 &  0 \end{bmatrix}$.